# My Vbscript seems to be having some unknown error, but is working properly?

Tags: vbscript

OK the code is working like it should. It gets a number then transmits that to a letter(`1=a,2=b,3=c,etc...`) but it seems to be repeating letters much more than it should for example it says this

Output:

```
    fffqqqqqqvxquukgggdrsp!biiirsssx!!xxrrrrghddaaayyvvtttjdeexxxvvvzzeuzz!u zzzzqp..qxxxttg!feeeee,,,,,
```

It randomly selects these characters, but there are 68 of them in the actual code and it seems that too much of a coincidence that it should repeat so often so much. Is the `Sendkeys` simply repeating itself somehow before it can loop?

Here's the code:

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Dim max
max = InputBox("Max number of characters (Numbers Only!)", _
    "Enter Integer")


If max = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
elseif max < 0 Then
    Wscript.Quit
end if

max = CInt( max )

i = 0

intAnswer = _
    Msgbox("Do you want to open a new Notepad?", _
        vbYesNo, "New Notepad")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    ws.Run "notepad.exe"
End If

Wscript.sleep 3000

do while max > i

i = i + 1

Randomize


rand = Int((3 - 1 + 1) * rnd + 1)

    if rand = 1 then
        char = "a"
    elseif rand = 2 then
        char = "b"
    elseif rand = 3 then
        char = "c"
    elseif rand = 4 then
        char = "."
    elseif rand = 5 then
        char = ","
    elseif rand = 6 then
        char = "!"
    elseif rand = 7 then
        char = "?"
    elseif rand = 8 then
        char = " "
    elseif rand = 9 then
        char = "{ENTER}"
    end if

    Wscript.sleep 75
    ws.Sendkeys char

    loop

    Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be after a random number between one and 9

The correct code for this is

```
rand = Int( rnd * 9) + 1
```

rnd generates a random *value* anywhere between zero and one.

Comment: Don't forget [`Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38d7ckek(v=vs.84).aspx) or the seed will not change.

Comment: um no im sorry but i forgot to change that the problem is the same char is repeating when i use `Sendkeys` and that is not correct to get the random number it is                                                                                             
                                                                                                          `Randomize
                                                                                                                                                                                          

rand = Int((max - min + 1) * rnd + min)`

Comment: there i just fixed it